# How to submit an object of data via POST, not ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

My data looks like this, it's just an object, with two objects in it (each representing the data of a form).

```
Object {x__sf: Object, x__mx: Object}
  x__mx: Object
    country_id: "1"
    input1: ""
    input2: ""
    ...
  x__sf: Object
    ...
```

I think I'll have to make a temporary form in memory and submit that? I'm not sure a safe way of looping through my data and adding hidden fields to the temporary form. Is there a function for this? Or better way?

I want to do this, but have it actually submit the page, because there's redirect logic serverside.

```
$.post('/whatever.php', data);
```

Comment: Stringify it, and then reencode it on the serverside.

Comment: Stringify it as a field on the temporary form? Good idea

Comment: You can use $.extend to extend an object, or you could just add a new property to the object and then stringify with whatever method floats your boat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But what is the problem with the following approach?

*Server side:*

```
<?php
// do some stuff
print "/redirect/to.php";
?>
```

*Client side:*

```
$.post("/whatever.php", data, function(data) {
    location.href = data;
});
```

---

Or even more advanced:

*Server side:*

```
<?php
// do some stuff
header("Content-Type: application/json");
print json_encode(array(
    "success" => "/redirect/to.php"
));
?>
```

*Client side:*

```
$.post("/whatever.php", data, function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
        location.href = data.success;
    }
}, "json");
```

Comment: +1, this is the approach I would use. As for a non-AJAX solution, however, this thread looks like what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Comment: @sgroves I don't think that function will work for my multidimensional object though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother looping.... do something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

Or in you're case:

```
var data = $("#idOfForm").serialize();
```

Comment: I don't have a form, just a json object. making the form is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to stringify your data before you send it:

```
$.post('/whatever.php', JSON.stringify(data));
```

On the server side, you need to use the PHP `json_decode()` function:

```
json_decode(http_get_request_body());
```